# How to change background color when changing orientation in Android?

Tags: android

I'm kind of new to Android Studio and appmaking. I wonder how to change the background color when a user shift his device from portrait mode, to landscape?

Example:
White background color in portrait mode, 
Green background color in landscape mode,

Comment: Just use 2 different layouts. One for landscape mode and one for portrait mode. Nothing could be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the color on onConfigurationChange

```
  @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        findViewById(R.id.mainLayout).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        findViewById(R.id.mainLayout).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be in my .java file for which activity this should be applied on? Or is it supposed to go in manifest or something?

Comment: In your java file, replace R.id.mainlayout for your lauyout

Comment: I don't have mainlayout anywhere in my java file?

This is what I've got:
http://imgur.com/a/QYB4j

Comment: replace R.id.mainLayout for the layout that is in activitysecond.xml

Comment: My activitysecond.xml doesn't have R.id.mainLayout either? Am I missing something?
http://imgur.com/a/H0UUr

Comment: set the id to the relative layout and replace the r.id.mainlayout by that id

Comment: I don't know what you mean by r.id.mainlayout. I can't find it?

Comment: Yes, but I can't find any id for my layout in activitysecond.xml? I'm sorry, I really try to understand you. This is how it looks like now http://imgur.com/a/tRo82

Comment: In the folder layouts there is a xml file, in that file inside the relative layout set an android:id and then replace what is red in my code with that id

Comment: Almost there now, I get no errors and I think I've made it right with the id in relative layout. Please take a look: http://imgur.com/a/Y2LUr

The only problem now is that the background color doesn't change when I tilt the emulator phone to landscape? I've cleaned and rebuilt the project

Comment: Try it on a real device

Comment: I solved it, instead of using two super, I declared X with Configuration x  = getResources().getConfiguration(); instead of newConfig! Thanks your help!

Comment: Awesome, glad to help

Answer (score 4):

You can provide different colors for "portrait" and "landscape" and reference them by the same resource id:

Let's assume you have a color resource, e.g. in res/values/colors.xml

```
<color name="my_background_color">#ffffff</color>
```

This color will be used as the default color with resource id `R.color.my_background_color` if there is no other more specific declaration.

In order to override the default for device orientation "landscape", you have to create a folder `values-land` as a sibling of `values`. In this folder, create a file `colors.xml` and inside this file:

```
<color name="my_background_color">#00ff00</color>
```

Then use the color as background color for your layout:

```
android:background="@color/my_background_color"
```

See also [Using configuration qualifiers](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers)